# CSS, Starting off new webpage, Trying to get the nav bar in the middle and at 95% width (2,5% on each side free)

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get this code to show up my nav bar in the middle and at 95% (2,5% on each side free). I have found a few ways on internet but they would require me to use a different style I want to keep it the same.

```css
#nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #0066cc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#nav .active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #0066cc;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #0066cc;
}

#nav .inactive {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-color: #0066cc;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #0066cc;
}

Html part:
```

```html
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="../HTML/Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/SocialNews.html">Social News</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Gallary.html">Gallary</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/CustomerReviews.html">Customer Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Sponsorship.html">Sponsorship</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Cart.html">Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the width to 95% and the margin left to 2.5%?

Comment: it jumps to the left not really changing much

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: 95%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to make the menu 95% width and centered.

Then add `display: flex` to the menu and `flex: 1 0 0` to the `li`'s to stretch those elements so they'll fill up the menu.

```css
#nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#nav li {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #0066cc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#nav .active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #0066cc;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #0066cc;
}

#nav .inactive {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-color: #0066cc;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #0066cc;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="../HTML/Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/SocialNews.html">Social News</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Gallary.html">Gallary</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/CustomerReviews.html">Customer Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Sponsorship.html">Sponsorship</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="../HTML/Cart.html">Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Almost worked, only the Customer reviews takes up 2 lines and therefore it shows up out of line of the others. (and also another tab, but due to still working on this page I can't publish that tab as it gives away the site).